# Fullcalendar support for WCF JSON output

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, fullcalendar

I have the following json output from a wcf service and would like to display it in a jquery calendar (fullcalendar). I'm having trouble getting things going, the calendar renders fine, but the events wont appear regardless of what I try. The json is here:

```
{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(1332153000000+0000)\/","BookingID":1,"BookingName":"Test Event","BookingStart":"\/Date(1332149400000+0000)\/","RoomID":8}
```

My question is, can this format be rendered in fullcalendar, or will I have to reformat in order to get my events? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to set your allDay to false within the json. The default is true and if you are not displaying the allDay slot than it will not appear on screen. set the allDay property to false and let me know if it helps.

**EDIT**

Every event must be associated with an id and an allDay Keyword such as...

```
id: '',
start: '',
allDay: false
```

Which must be set to true or false...

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/allDaySlot/

These are the built in properties...

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: Hi Juan. I am a little confused when you say set the allDay property to false. Does this mean I have to return the specific event format from my json?

Comment: does this specific format have to be returned from my service which provides the JSON? Or can I return the string as it is above and convert that way? Thanks.

Comment: It must be returned as a string, the Json back end will set the format.

Answer (score 0):

Also unless you have edited FullCalendar I think you need to use the expected keywords id, start, end (note that jscript is case sensitive)

Comment: Is it possible to convert this json in the jquery page and load it that way?

Comment: @Mych this is not true, I used to think that way too until I tried different keywords. Now I am using things like team_name, team_id, etc. FullCalendar is not confined.

Comment: @Juan Gonzales Thanks... I knew you could add your own attributes but I was sure FullCalendar still expected 'id' and 'start' (end I'm  not sure about as it could be an all day event)